# Dart equivalent to Python zip and list comprehension for generating list of widgets from two lists

Tags: python, list, dart, list-comprehension

I want to create a list of widgets `MyWidget(categoryName, color)` from the following two lists.

```dart
  static const _categoryNames = <String>[
    'Length',
    'Area',
    'Volume',
  ];

  static const _baseColors = <Color>[
    Colors.teal,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.pinkAccent,
  ];
```

In Python I would use a list comprehension with zip to get the result.

```py
my_widget_list = [MyWidget(categoryName, baseColor) for categoryName, baseColor in zip(_categoryNames, _baseColors)]
```

Googling for a similar method for Dart did not provide any satisfactory solution.

Comment: Why not just rebuild the input params to allow a simple map function? F.e `List<Map<String, Color>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your aim is to create a list of widgets (assuming both your lists will have same number of elements). You can try

```
List<Widget> getWidgets() {

  List<Widget> my_widget_list = [];
  const _categoryNames = <String>[
    'Length',
    'Area',
    'Volume',
  ];

 const _baseColors = <Color>[
    Colors.teal,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.pinkAccent,
  ];

  for (int i = 0; i <= _categoryNames.length -1 ; i++){
    my_widget_list.add(MyWidget(_categoryNames[i],_baseColors[i]));
  }

  return my_widget_list;
  }

Widget MyWidget(String categoryName, Color baseColor){
  return Container(
    color: baseColor,
    child: Text(categoryName,));
}
```

Comment: This is the better solution, but I feel like a caveman having to iterate using indexes like in C . Very 80s. Dart should address this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`zip` function from `package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/zip.html).  Combined with *collection-for* (Dart's equivalent to Python list comprehensions) can get you most of the way there.  Dart does not have Python's automatic unpacking, so unfortunately you won't get nice variable names:

```dart
my_widget_list = [
  for (var pair in zip([_categoryNames, _baseColors]))
    MyWidget(pair[0], pair[1]),
]
```

Comment: This solution is looking great but it did give me an error.

Comment: @MachineLearner Oops, I made a couple of typos.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

## "Pythonic" Dart Syntax

You can do something that looks very similar to Python using [Control Flow Collections](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/control-flow-collections/feature-specification.md).

```dart
    List<Widget> myWidgetList = [
      for (String name in categoryNames)
        for (Color color in baseColors)
          if (baseColors.indexOf(color) == categoryNames.indexOf(name))
            myWidget(name, color)
    ];
```

Maybe a little less "Pythonic" but more concise . . .

```dart
    List<Widget> myWidgetList = [
      for (String name in categoryNames)
        myWidget(name, baseColors[categoryNames.indexOf(name)])
    ];
```

Specifically, you should read over [Control Flow Collections: Composing](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/control-flow-collections/feature-specification.md#composing)

## Complete Unit Test

For you convenience here is a quick unit-test you can run.

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('build list of widgets with composing', () {
    List<Widget> myWidgetList = [
      for (String name in categoryNames)
        for (Color color in baseColors)
          if (baseColors.indexOf(color) == categoryNames.indexOf(name))
            myWidget(name, color)
    ];

    List<Widget> myOtherWidgetList = [
      for (String name in categoryNames)
        myWidget(name, baseColors[categoryNames.indexOf(name)])
    ];

    expect(myWidgetList.length, equals(myOtherWidgetList.length));
    expect(myWidgetList.toString(), equals(myOtherWidgetList.toString()));
    print(myWidgetList);
  });
}

const categoryNames = <String>[
  'Length',
  'Area',
  'Volume',
];
const baseColors = <Color>[
  Colors.teal,
  Colors.orange,
  Colors.pinkAccent,
];

Widget myWidget(String categoryName, Color baseColor) {
  return Container(
      color: baseColor,
      child: Text(
        categoryName,
      ));
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient: it turns what should be an O(n) operation into an O(n^2) operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map.fromIterables` and loop over the result of `.entries` method to sort of do the same thing as zip in Python:

```dart
  const _categoryNames = <String>[
    'Length',
    'Area',
    'Volume',
  ];

  const _baseColors = <Color>[
    Colors.teal,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.pinkAccent,
  ];
  
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
  for (final entry in Map.fromIterables(_categoryNames, _baseColors).entries) {
    widgets.add(MyWidet(entry.key, entry.value));
  }
```

Here, `entry` is of type `MapEntry<String, Color>` where entry.key is the element from `_categoryNames` and entry.value is the corresponding element from `_baseColors`.
This can't be used for more that 2 iterables, unfortunately, but it's enough for most cases.